# Is it possible to duplicate a dashboard in grafana?

Tags: grafana

I need to create a dev dashboard very similar to an existing prod one, and was wondering if there was an easy way of copying the existing dashboard. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 149, accepted):

There is a "Save As..." button in the dashboard settings:

[image: Save As.. button in dashboard settings]

Comment: Confirmed.  Click the Dashboard name, click the gear, and do a save as.

Comment: Yes. I also often miss the "duplicate/clone" option ;-)

Comment: Careful, it seems like the original dashboard is overwritten, if you import an already existing dashboard. You have to change the uid in the json to avoid this.

Comment: Such a bad design from Grafana imo.

Answer (score 27):

Yes you can duplicate a dashboard. Just save it with a different name. Click on the save icon change the name and it will be saved with a new name (the old one will still exist)

Comment: It works! Click Dashboard 'Settings' > 'Save As'. Stores a new identical dashboard under new name.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, We can duplicate the dashboard,

Setting--> Save As.

Settings view:

[image: Settings view]

Comment: This works fine for me. Prior dashboard still exists, new one is saved with new name.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up doing this by exporting the existing dashboard, re-importing it, making my changes, and then saving it with a different title.

Answer (score 4):

Personally i would create Template and you can Switch from Dev / Stage / Prod... that way you don't have to duplicate your work, no more Save As etc.

[image]

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.